# Making page refresh inside jquery

Tags: php, javascript

So I have a count down timer. After the timer hits 0 I need it to update the database and then refresh the page.

Here is what I have so far for the timer / update database.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){

(function(){
  var counter = <?php echo $timer ; ?>;

  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (counter === 0) {


        document.getElementById( "response" ).innerHTML = "<div style=\"float: right; display: inline-block; margin: 6px;\"><div class=\"skip_btn\"><?php $sqll = "UPDATE users SET coins=coins+? WHERE username=?";
    $q = $db->prepare($sqll);
    $q->execute(array('1',$_SESSION['username']));$sqll2 = "UPDATE websites SET clicks_left=clicks_left-? WHERE id=?";
    $q2 = $db->prepare($sqll2);
    $q2->execute(array('1',$row['id']));?></div></div><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
    }

  }, 1000);

})();

}
</script>
```

So this works fine for the timer and the database update but now i need to add a refresh in side of there which i try and do like so.

```
document.getElementById( "response" ).innerHTML = "<div style=\"float: right; display: inline-block; margin: 6px;\"><div class=\"skip_btn\"><?php $sqll = "UPDATE users SET coins=coins+? WHERE username=?";
    $q = $db->prepare($sqll);
    $q->execute(array('1',$_SESSION['username']));$sqll2 = "UPDATE websites SET clicks_left=clicks_left-? WHERE id=?";
    $q2 = $db->prepare($sqll2);
    $q2->execute(array('1',$row['id']));echo'<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=dashboard.php">';?></div></div><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
```

But then the timer stops working all together....
Also php headers do not work on my server ( headers all ready sent error )
I need it so when the timer hits 0 it will refresh the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use PHP inside of Javascript like that. You would need to use Javascript (i.e AJAX) to call a server-side PHP script to perform the database queries and return the data to Javascript to populate onto the page.

It seems you really need to try to understand the separation between server-side logic (PHP in your case) and client side logic (Javascript). What is happening now is that you are echoing your PHP code into the Javascript `script` tag, which is obviously invalid Javascript.

Comment: Could i ask why the php works then ?? With out the redirect ? If it does not ment to work ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't initially see the opening and closing PHP tags within the `script` due to the formatting not being very clear.  This works , the only problem is that it happens before the page is rendered in the client. At this point the results of the database calls are static from the clients perspective. The function will just set the innerHTML value to the same thing each time it loops. You would still need to make an AJAX call to a server script to get any updated information from the database.